# Sum of indexes of the nearest larger neighbours of each array element

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

> Given an array A with N number of elements, for each element \$i\$
>   (\$1 \le i \le N\$), find \$x + y\$, where \$x\$ is the largest number less than \$i\$ such that \$A[x] > A[i]\$ and \$y\$ is the smallest number greater than \$i\$ such that \$A[y] > A[i]\$.
>
> If there is no \$x < i\$ where \$A[x] > A[i]\$, \$x=-1\$, similarly
>
> If there is no \$y > i\$ where \$A[y] > A[i]\$, \$y=-1\$
>
> **The tricky part is:**
>
> \$1 \le N \le 10^6\$
>
> \$1 \le A[i] \le 10^{18}\$
>
> **Sample**
>
> **Input**:
>
> ```
> 5
>
> 5 4 1 3 2
> ```
>
> **Output**:
>
> ```
> -2 0 6 1 3
> ```

This is failing a few test cases:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i; 
    cin >> n;
    long int a[n];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    int x,y,c,d,s1,s2;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        c=0;
        d=0;
        s1=-1;
        s2=-1;
        x=i-1;
        while(x>0){
            if(a[x]>a[i]){
                s1=x;
                break;
            }
            else{ 
                x--;
            }
        }
        y=i+1;
            while(y<=n){
                if(a[y]>a[i]){
                    s2=y;
                    break;
                }
                else 
                    y++;
            }
        int s=s1+s2;
        cout << s << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that your code has a bug.  0 is a valid index but your while loop exits when `x == 0`.  It should probably be set for `x>=0`.

Comment: You say it's "failing a few test cases".  Is it *functionally incorrect*, or is it merely *insufficiently performant*?  That's the difference between unready and ready for review.

Comment: Two comments either way: VLAs are not a C++ thing, and using namespace std is bad mojo.

Answer (score 4):

The code is almost unreadable.  The single-letter variable names don't convey very much, the indentation is inconsistent, and the logic is opaque.

I'd start by dropping `using namespace std;` and separating the I/O from the program logic so that you can at least code a few test cases to ease debugging and improvement.

That variable-sized array looks risky, even with compilers that support that (non-standard) extension.  Even with moderate limit of n < 1 million, that's still quite a lot to put on your stack.  Consider allocating with `new[]` or (better) using a `std::vector`.

And what are `c` and `d` for?  They are both set to zero, but never used.

Further points:

`long int` may have a size of just 32 bits at a minimum, meaning a maximum range of up to 2,147,483,647.  To guarantee you can hold positive integers up to 1e18, you'll want an `unsigned long long`, or (better) `std::uint_least64_t`.  Similarly, the range of `int` may be only -32,767 to 32,767, so I'd suggest `std::uint_least32_t` for the index values.

Here's how I would restructure the program:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

using Integer = std::uint_least64_t;
using IndexSum = std::int_least32_t;

std::vector<Integer> read_input(std::istream& in);
std::vector<IndexSum> add_closest_indices_of_greater_values(const std::vector<Integer>&);

#include <iostream>
#if TEST
int main()
{
    std::vector<IndexSum> actual = add_closest_indices_of_greater_values({
        5, 4, 1, 3, 2
    });
    std::vector<IndexSum>expected = {-2, 0, 6, 1, 3 };
    if (actual == expected)
        return 0;

    for (const auto& a: {actual, expected}) {
        for (auto n: a)
            std::cerr << n << " ";
        std::cerr << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
#else
int main()
{
    std::vector<Integer> a = read_input(std::cin);
    std::vector<Integer> b = add_closest_indices_of_greater_values(a);
    for (auto n: b)
        std::cout << n << " ";
}
#endif
```

You can then compile with `TEST` defined, and refine `add_closest_indices_of_greater_values()` until you get the correct output:

```
std::vector<IndexSum> add_closest_indices_of_greater_values(const std::vector<Integer>& a)
{
    std::vector<IndexSum> out;
    auto n = a.size();
    out.reserve(n);
    for(auto i=0u;  i<n;  i++){
        IndexSum s1 = -1;
        IndexSum s2 = -1;
        // search for nearest prior element greater than this one
        for (auto x = i;  0 < x;  --x) {
            if (a[x-1] > a[i]) {
                s1 = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        // search for nearest following element greater than this one
        for (auto x = i+1;  x < n;  ++x) {
            if (a[x] > a[i]) {
                s2 = x+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        out.push_back(s1+s2);
    }
    return out;
}
```

And it's a simple matter to read the input:

```
std::vector<Integer> read_input(std::istream& in)
{
    std::vector<Integer> a;
    in.exceptions(std::istream::failbit);

    std::size_t n;
    in >> n;
    a.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 0u;  i < n;  ++i)
        in >> a[i];

    return a;
}
```

All you need to do now is to improve the algorithm so it no longer performs a linear search for each element.  You may want to instrument how many times you dereference the array, in order to reduce the complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, valid indices to `a[n]` are `0 .. n-1`. The loop `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` accesses memory beyond the array, which invokes undefined behaviour.

---

The algorithm has a quadratic time complexity. There is a linearithmic solution (since it seems to be a competitive programming question, I will not spell the algorithm out).